# Create list of integers on an interval

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create a list of integers on an interval increasing with a certain step, for example [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. How could I do this without creating a separate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 2**

To create an array of Ints in sequence you can use a "range":

```
let a = Array(0...10)  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Here `0...10` makes the Range and the Array initializer makes the Range into an Array of Ints.

There's also this variant:

```
let a = Array(0..<10)  // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And to do the same thing but with a different stepping, you can use "stride":

```
let b = Array(0.stride(through: 10, by: 2))  // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Here `stride` starts on 0 and goes through 10 by steps of 2.

It also has a variant:

```
let b = Array(0.stride(to: 10, by: 2))  // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

**Swift 3**

The syntax for `stride` has changed, now it's a free function.

```
let b = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 10, by: 2))  // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
let b = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 10, by: 2))  // [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```